# pandas-dev installation (How to install Pandas 1.3.0)

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen that on Pandas version 1.3.0.dev0+1779.gdcc2a8f801 there is a new implemented method (read_xml) and I would like to use it. The problem is that I have not found a way to install a development version of Pandas. i am currently using Python3 and pip and have tried from its source repository ([Pandas-dev page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/))

How could I deal with that? Maybe using Conda or compiling it myself? I don't know exactcly how to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pip would not have this release with it and there are no binaries given with that version of Pandas yet so I would recommend building it from source.

You can go [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases/tag/v1.3.0.dev0) and download the source code, extract it and then build it.

The instructions to build it are given [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas#installation-from-sources).

Answer (score 2):

You can use pip:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas.git
```

If you are using a jupyter notebook, just run:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas.git
```

it will install the last version:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas.git
  Cloning https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-lpoyr70w
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Successfully built pandas
Installing collected packages: pandas
  Attempting uninstall: pandas
    Found existing installation: pandas 1.2.5
    Uninstalling pandas-1.2.5:
      Successfully uninstalled pandas-1.2.5
Successfully installed pandas-1.4.0.dev0+108.gfa6b96e128
```

If you want a specific version, just add at the end @ and choose a commit checkout you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the latest dev release of pandas with:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas
```